InvalidGrpcDecoratorException [Error]: The invalid gRPC decorator (method "createUser" in service "UserService") throwing error
    // Code generated by protoc-gen-ts_proto. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//   protoc-gen-ts_proto  v2.6.0
//   protoc               v5.29.1
// source: user.proto

/* eslint-disable */
import { Metadata } from "@grpc/grpc-js";
import { GrpcMethod, GrpcStreamMethod } from "@nestjs/microservices";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export const protobufPackage = "user_service";

export interface User {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  hashedPassword: string;
  role: string;
  bio: string;
  isVerified: boolean;
  profileImageUrl: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  phoneNumber: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  username: string;
}

export interface CreateUserRequest {
  user?: User | undefined;
}

export interface CreateUserResponse {
  success: boolean;
  message: string;
}

export const USER_SERVICE_PACKAGE_NAME = "user_service";

export interface UserServiceClient {
  createUser(request: CreateUserRequest, metadata?: Metadata): Observable<CreateUserResponse>;
}

export interface UserServiceController {
  createUser(
    request: CreateUserRequest,
    metadata?: Metadata,
  ): Promise<CreateUserResponse> | Observable<CreateUserResponse> | CreateUserResponse;
}

export function UserServiceControllerMethods() {
  return function (constructor: Function) {
    const grpcMethods: string[] = ["createUser"];
    for (const method of grpcMethods) {
      const descriptor: any = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(constructor.prototype, method);
      GrpcMethod("UserService", method)(constructor.prototype[method], method, descriptor);
    }
    const grpcStreamMethods: string[] = [];
    for (const method of grpcStreamMethods) {
      const descriptor: any = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(constructor.prototype, method);
      GrpcStreamMethod("UserService", method)(constructor.prototype[method], method, descriptor);
    }
  };
}

export const USER_SERVICE_NAME = "UserService";

this is the generated file for the user.proto using protoc
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { join } from 'path';

async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options: {
      package: 'user_service',
      protoPath: join(__dirname, './infrastructure/grpc/protos/user.proto'), 
      url: 'localhost:50051', 
    },
  });
  
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transform: true,
    }),
  );
  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();

and the above one is my main file for the server
my proto file
syntax = "proto3";

package user_service;

option go_package = "user_service";

message User {
  string id = 1;
  string email = 2;
  string hashed_password = 3;
  string role = 4;
  string bio = 5;
  bool is_verified = 6;
  string profile_image_url = 7;
  bool is_active = 8;
  string phone_number = 9;
  string date_of_birth = 10;
  string username = 11;
}

message CreateUserRequest {
  User user = 1;
}

message CreateUserResponse {
  bool success = 1;
  string message = 2;
}

service UserService {
  rpc CreateUser(CreateUserRequest) returns (CreateUserResponse);
}


import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GrpcMethod } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { CreateUserRequest, CreateUserResponse } from '../../generated/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  @GrpcMethod('UserService', 'CreateUser')
  async createUser(request: CreateUserRequest): Promise<CreateUserResponse> {
    console.log('Received user creation request:', request);
    return {
      success: true,
      message: 'User created successfully',
    };
  }
}

here i got the error  i tried different ways to fix this but nothing works . everytime same error getting . in my opinion both proto file and user service have same methods
$ nest start
C:\user-service\node_modules@nestjs\microservices\decorators\message-pattern.decorator.js:51
throw new invalid_grpc_message_decorator_exception_1.InvalidGrpcDecoratorException(metadata);
^
InvalidGrpcDecoratorException [Error]: The invalid gRPC decorator (method "createUser" in service "UserService")
